# Display Woocommerce product price with and without tax and tax amount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, tax

I am using WooCommerce for WordPress and I'm listing items excluding Tax.

I need to show **separately** the Price *(without tax)*, the Tax and the PRICE + Tax on the product page *(like in checkout page)*.

I have not been able to find a plugin that does this.

How can I do this?

Comment: type error: separately

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**WooCommerce v3.0.0 and Later**
As of WooCommerce version 3.0, the function [woocommerce_price()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_price.html#485-491)  is deprecated, as is the method [get_price_including_tax()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product.html).  Instead, you should use [wc_get_price_including_tax](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_price_including_tax.html):

```
<?php echo wc_price( wc_get_price_including_tax( $product ) ); ?>
```

**Prior to WooCommerce v3.0.0**
You need to modify a template.  **Do not** modify the core WooCommerce template, but rather make a copy of it to your theme, using the WooCommerce template override system.  For help with that, refer to the WooCommerce docs on using the [template override system](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/).

In the `price.php` template, you will add this bit of code where you want the price, including tax (VAT):

```
<?php echo woocommerce_price( $product->get_price_including_tax() ); ?>
```

Note: the `price.php` template that you modify should be located here in `wp-content/themes/[your theme folder]/woocommerce/single-product/price.php`

Answer (score 18):

**Update 2018/2019** *(for Woocommerce 3+)*

**To display price without tax + tax amount + price including tax *(on separated lines)*:**

First read ["How to override Woocommerce templates via your theme"](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

**1) On [`single-product/price.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.5/templates/single-product/price.php) template file** *(single product pages)*.

Replace the code with:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;

// Get the prices
$price_excl_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product ); // price without VAT
$price_incl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax( $product );  // price with VAT
$tax_amount     = $price_incl_tax - $price_excl_tax; // VAT amount

// Display the prices
?>
<p class="price-excl"><?php echo wc_price( $price_excl_tax ); ?></p>
<p class="tax-price"><?php  echo wc_price( $tax_amount ); ?></p>
<p class="price-incl"><?php echo wc_price( $price_incl_tax ); ?></p>
```

**2) On [`loop/price.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.5/templates/loop/price.php) template file** *(Shop and archive pages)*.

Replace the code with:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;

if ( $product->get_price_html() ) :
    // Get the prices
    $price_excl_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product ); // price without VAT
    $price_incl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax( $product );  // price with VAT
    $tax_amount     = $price_incl_tax - $price_excl_tax; // VAT amount

    // Display the prices
    ?>
    <span class="price price-excl"><?php echo wc_price( $price_excl_tax ); ?></span><br>
    <span class="price tax-price"><?php  echo wc_price( $tax_amount ); ?></span><br>
    <span class="price price-incl"><?php echo wc_price( $price_incl_tax ); ?></span>
<?php endif ?>
```

Documentation: 
• [Template structure and how to override Woocommerce templates via your theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) 
• [`wc_get_price_including_tax()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_price_including_tax.html#895-953) product price function 
• [`wc_get_price_excluding_tax()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_price_excluding_tax.html#955-987) product price function 
• [`wc_price()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_price.html#505-563) formatting price function 
• [`wc_get_price_to_display()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_price_to_display.html#989-1007) product price function

---

Original answer *(before woocommerce 3)*:

Before check that your WooCommerce **Tax general settings** match with your needs.

As [cale_b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/870729/cale-b) suggested, you need to copy from woocommerce the `templates` folder inside your active child theme or theme. Then rename it `woocommerce`. In this `woocommerce` templates folder you will find inside `single-product` subfolder the **price.php** template to edit related to pricing display in single product pages.

In **`single-product/price.php`** template file just after `global $product;`,
replace the code with:

```
?>
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
<?php
    $price_excl = $product->get_price_excluding_tax(); // price without VAT
    $price_incl = $product->get_price_including_tax();  // price included VAT
    $tax_amount = $price_incl - $price_excl; // VAT price amount
?>
    <p class="price"><?php echo woocommerce_price( $price_excl ); /* without VAT */ ?></p> (formatted)
    <p class="price-vat"><?php echo woocommerce_price( $tax_amount); /* VAT */ ?></p>
    <p class="price-and-vat"><?php echo woocommerce_price( $price_incl); /* With VAT  */ ?></p> 

    <meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_price() ); ?>" />
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo esc_attr( get_woocommerce_currency() ); ?>" />
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/<?php echo $product->is_in_stock() ? 'InStock' : 'OutOfStock'; ?>" />
</div>
```

Because the additional prices are unformatted, you may need to mix some other elements with this additionals prices using some woocommerce php functions like:

```
get_price_suffix( ) // Get the suffix to display after prices > 0.
$currency = esc_attr( get_woocommerce_currency( ) ) // Get the currency code.
get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $currency ) // Get the currency symbol.
get_tax_class( ) // Returns the tax class.
get_tax_status( ) // Returns the tax status.
```

Reference: [WooCommerce WC_Product class](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html)

Comment: This works well for products (variable or simple) that have the same prices. It doesn't however show the price range, such as £8.95 - £9.95 that WooCommerce normally displays where variations have different prices. Is it possible to achieve the same for inc/exc. taxes and also include text to make it clear for the customers? 

For example: 
Price exc. VAT: £8.95 - £9.95 
Price inc. VAT: £10.74 - £11.94

Answer (score 7):

At the moment you don't need to change a template anymore. You can set this in the Woocommerce settings:

- Woocommerce: Tax tab: Display Prices in the Shop / Display Prices During Cart and Checkout

Comment: There is no option to show both at the same time, so still not best answer for all cases

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you don't have to edit templates to show VAT. Go to Woocommerce settings > VAT > Price Display suffix. You can add: {price_excluding_tax} to show without VAT.